# wordpress выборка записи

Tags: php, wordpress

В шаблоне wordpress не могу нормально настроить отображение записей

для index.php
выбор по определенной рубрике в цикле выглядит так

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query('cat=2');
if( $query->have_posts() ){
while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post();
?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем переменную $post
} 
else echo 'Записей нет.';
?>
```

мне нужно чтобы у каждой рубрики был свой настраиваемый шаблон,
поэтому я пытаюсь прикрутить чтото подобное для файла single.php, но у меня не получается

прошу помочь!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужны шаблоны для каждой рубрики (категории), то это делается через иерархию шаблонов.

Т.е. шаблон для категории с идентификатором 2 должен быть в файле category-2.php

Есть и другие варианты.

[Подробнее: Category Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

Comment: Спасибо
решил через условие http://www.floomby.ru/s2/Yg82bh/full/